# Deleted files still accessible without www in url

Tags: 301-redirect, webserver, http, ftp, no-www

I have deleted all files and all hidden files off my server, there is nothing but log files which cannot be deleted.

Ironically, files are accessible when nothing is there.  Cache cleared, multiple browsers and computers/devices checked.

Files show when I exclude "www" from the URL

`http://sarastringfellow.com/assets/photo/c.jpg`

`http://www.sarastringfellow.com/assets/photo/c.jpg`

***What does this mean?***

Comment: I get a 404 on both URLs. I'd guess that your files had to have been loading from a server cache.

Comment: I get a 404 error on both links too.

Comment: me too, it must have finally refreshed.  thanks guys.

Comment: server cache finally refreshed...

Comment: I actually see the image on both URLs!? (And it's the first time I have visited those URLs.) - A B&W photo of a lady lying on the beach looking at the camera.

Comment: @w3d Me as well. Is this a CDN behavior?

Comment: I can confirm that I also still see the photo on both URLs.

Comment: Ironically, nothing was deleted!!! All show still to this date???

Answer (score 1):

Deleted? You don't delete files when you don't want people accessing domainname.com without the www.

You should use a .htaccess in the root of your wordpress install folder.

Make this file '.htaccess' with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sarastringfellow\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sarastringfellow.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will make anyone attempting to view the site or images without the www redirect to the site which has www. before it.

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting company may have cached them or copied them to a second server. I've come across this and had to put in a support ticket to the hosting company explaining i've deleted all files from the root folder and they still appear. The hosting company had to do the deletion from whatever server they had been copied to.